# C# Cannot communicate using Http/Web/Smtp clients, including 3rd party libraries

Tags: c#, smtp, httprequest, restsharp

When I launch my application, sometimes all the network related calls end up being non-responsive, timing out throwing exceptions. It can be "fixed" by restarting the application. This issue started happening after I reinstalled my system. I have no idea what may be the cause as it doesn't happen always and it is "bound" to the running executable, since either all or nothing works.

I'm using mix of Http/Web/Smtp and RestSharp request and all of them have the same status.

Here are the exceptions

```
A System.Net.Sockets.SocketException was thrown: "An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket"
A System.Net.WebException was thrown: "Unable to connect to the remote server"
A System.Net.WebException was thrown: "The operation has timed out"
```

Do you guys have any idea to point me in the right direction in debugging of this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Check your firewall/antivirus, looks like smth blocks your network activity.